# android load image from non http inputstream

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I have an url such as `192.16.7.10/myimage.png`

I am sure the file is not hosted as HTTP downloadable image.

What method i should use to get the image from the network stream.

The file is present in the root directory of a media server, running RAOP

I tried below,

```
public  class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadImageTask";
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Log.e(TAG,"icon url = "+urldisplay);
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    //  bmImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

but i got

```
09-03 09:18:27.735: W/System.err(14293): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.16.7.10/myimage.png
09-03 09:18:27.740: W/System.err(14293):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
09-03 09:18:27.740: W/System.err(14293):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
```

On request , the server sends the URL similar to `ipaddress/filename.fileformat`, without any port information, which implies the port to use is 80.

I once remember accessing UPnP Media  servers, who gives relative urls so that we should normalize it first which then gives an address such as `ipaddress:port/filename.fileformat`

Can any one help in accessing this file..

Comment: If you use `h ttp://192.16.7.10/myimage.png` then the file will be downloaded using the http protocol. It makes no sense speaking of 'being hosted as http'. If your url should work then the image should be located in the document root of the webserver. `On request , the server sends the URL`. Servers don't send urls. If you request a file then they send a file.

Comment: by `on request, the server sends the url,` which i wanted to insist is, The ServerSocket on the server side sends the url of the image to use... Thanks for mentioning `http://192.16.7.10/myimage.png`